# HighCharts Polar Chart: only display one quadrant?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create 3 polar charts with HighCharts that each only displays one quadrant of the circle.  And then put them together to form a cockeyed pac-man.  This way, each quadrant gets its own legend and scale.

I've pretty much successfully done it except that HighCharts outputs white space where the missing quadrants would be, resulting in a sad looking webpage:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdjavi/LAvtr/2/
(you may need to fullscreen your browser to see the desired effect)

Does anyone know if getting rid of that whitespace is an option?

```
    pane: {
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 0
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/LAvtr/4/

Three things you need to setup:

- for each pane set center, for example: `center: [350,150] //width and height` and size, e.g. `size: 200`
- for each chart set margins: `[0,0,0,0]`
- for each legend set `floating: true //won't take space on a chart`